# How to clone AWS container instance to google container

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, devops

I am looking for a way to clone or share AWS container instance to google container like we can share AWS S3 bucket data to Google cloud storage.
Like Instagram transfer their data from AWS to FB cloud.
https://www.wired.com/2014/06/facebook-instagram/

Or they just moved the pictures, not code or infrastructure? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for explicitly sharing running containers/instances between cloud vendors (as in managing them from one another). What you can do is sharing the images where these containers/instances are built with. If you are talking about complete machines or instances, basically what you can do is using the VM Import/Export feature that is available for Amazon machine images (previously taking an image from an ec2 instance), but you are bound to the limitations (you will also have to take licensing into account) that this service imposes.

If you are talking about containers, at the end they are just docker images, so you could use the docker hub to put your images and set the container services of both vendors to use said images.

If what you need is to have the instances running side by side, you can just set some sort of vpn and add your networking resources on both vendors to that "vpn"